# Enterprise architect: Navigate to last diagram

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'm looking for a button or key combination in Enterprise Architect (12.1) which is similar to the back button in a browser.

Consider the following scenario:

An activity diagram is composed of a few composite activities. By double clicking, I enter the activity graph of a composed activity. This graph might also contain composed activities which I enter by double clicking. After a few double clicks, I again want to look at one of the higher level graphs. Is there a way to go back to where I came from without having to browse the project browser?

I've searched the Internet and the EA documentation without luck, but I can't (and don't want to) believe that such a feature doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is simply close the last expanded diagram. That brings me back to where it has been expanded from.

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to install the EA Navigator add-in. Its window shows the last 50 selected things.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll have a look at this next week when I'm back at work.

Comment: As the author of the EA Navigator I like this solution best, but you should also try to hold the CTRL and while holding it press the Tab key. That will bring up a nice overview of all diagrams, including a preview of the diagram itself.

Comment: @GeertBellekens I found it hard to decide which answer to accept. Both are pretty useful. I chose the "Close last expanded diagram" answer by Thomas Kilian, as it helps me to be disciplined about not having huge amounts of windows open at the same time.

Comment: @GeertBellekens Life in EA without EA Navigator is a hard life. Especially when dealing with GUIDs.